# Getting an error that my tf has been ignored

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Bosch BN055 9-axis accelerometer and I have installed this package to integrate with ROS:
[LINK](https://github.com/romainreignier/rtimulib_ros)

However, when I run the whole launch file with odometry (odometry gets the IMU values from /imu topic, will put the code at the end), I get this error:

```
Error:   TF_DENORMALIZED_QUATERNION: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "base_footprint" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of an invalid quaternion in the transform (0.000000 0.000000 0.008824 -0.994081)
```

And here is the code where odometry gets the IMU orientation values (callback function):

```
void Odometry::ImuCb(const sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr& data)
{
    orient_z = data->orientation.z;
    orient_w = data->orientation.w;

}
```

And here where it puts into tf message:

```
geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat ;

    

    odom_quat.x = 0.0;
    odom_quat.y = 0.0;
    odom_quat.z = 0.0;

    odom_quat.z = this->orient_z;
    odom_quat.w = this->orient_w;

    geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
    odom_trans.header.stamp = now;
    odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
    odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_footprint";

        odom_trans.transform.translation.x = x_final;
        odom_trans.transform.translation.y = y_final;
        odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
        odom_trans.transform.rotation = odom_quat;

        odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312269/getting-an-error-that-my-tf-has-been-ignored/) by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 361 on 2019-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-09**:
The magnitude of the quaternion should be one for it to be valid, the magnitude of the one shown is `0.9882748975`, hence it is not valid.

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2019-01-09**:
@jayess Can it be -1?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-09**:
It's part of the definition of a quaternion. Please see the [quaternion tutorial on the wiki](https://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions). Magnitudes are not negative, so, no it should not be `-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quaternions are 4 element unit vectors, for some reason the code you've shown is only copying two of those four elements. Hence why the magnitude is smaller than it should be.

If you update the code so it copies all the elements of the quaternion (x y z and w) to the transform then hopefully this should fix your problem.

Let us know how you get on.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2019-01-09**:
Yes, I figured this out and the problem disappeared :)
Can you also look at my newest question? [LINK](https://answers.ros.org/question/312290/how-to-fuse-encoder-ticks-imu-for-odometry/)